# How to generate random int around specific mean?

Tags: python, random

I need to generate 100 age values between 23 and 72 and the mean value must be 42 years.

Do you think such a function already exists in standard python? If not, I think I know python just enough and should be able to code the algorithm but I am hoping something is already there for use. Any hints?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: Hint: say you generated 100 age values but their mean *wasn't* 42 years.  What could you to do change that?

Comment: I've skimmed through the random docs but did not find anything. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Thats a good question @DSM

Comment: What actual distribution do you want? What you've said isn't precise enough to tell what you want. If we suggest anything before we know what you want, the most probable result is that you'll tell us the results don't have some necessary property you didn't realize was important to mention.

Comment: I am not sure about the distribution actually. The requirement is written in the post.

Comment: If that's the whole requirement, you could just produce 50% 41-year-olds and 50% 43-year olds or 61% 23-year olds, 39% 72-year-olds. You probably have other requirements you don't even think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could populate an array of size 100 with all 42s as the entries.

Then randomly choose two indices, check their values and adjust by 1 if they are acceptable.

I'm just guessing here but this is what I did, not really sure what the distribution ends up being but the average is dead on and eye balling the values it looks to cover the range fairly evenly... Sorry its messy but I just wanted to throw something together really quick before I leave work!

```
def age_arr():
    age_A = []
    for _i in range(100):
        age_A.append(42)

    for _i in range(100000):
        rand_ind_1 = randint(0,99)
        rand_ind_2 = randint(0,99)

        val_1 = age_A[rand_ind_1] #Subtract from
        val_2 = age_A[rand_ind_2] #Add to

        if val_1 == 23 or val_2 == 72:
            age_A[rand_ind_1] += 1
            age_A[rand_ind_2] -= 1

        age_A[rand_ind_1] -= 1
        age_A[rand_ind_2] += 1
    sum = 0
    for val in age_A:
        sum += val
    print(age_A)
    print('Average: ' + str(sum/100))
```

Output:

```
[29, 27, 51, 68, 28, 40, 72, 42, 41, 31, 59, 46, 61, 52, 43, 26, 34, 29, 41, 23,
 37, 27, 45, 23, 49, 43, 28, 24, 60, 43, 65, 57, 27, 46, 35, 52, 23, 34, 47, 39,
 64, 52, 46, 48, 30, 27, 23, 30, 57, 34, 46, 26, 29, 30, 55, 72, 34, 52, 66, 38,
 69, 34, 24, 40, 39, 59, 67, 39, 39, 26, 70, 36, 31, 50, 29, 59, 64, 52, 40, 33,
 62, 32, 53, 41, 45, 24, 47, 27, 23, 39, 68, 24, 34, 36, 56, 36, 32, 49, 40, 26]
Average: 42.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. It is `random.triangular(min, max, av)`.

Your mean value will be close, but not equal to av.

Edit: see comments below, this has drawbacks.

Comment: There are others too. Why triangular?

Comment: The third argument is the mode, not the mean, so this produces results with a mean notably skewed closer to the middle of the distribution than the third argument would suggest.

Comment: Thanks but I need it to be rather precise.

Comment: @juanchopanza, that is actually a good question. Triangular should give symetric values. But I'm not sure enough it would be good in this case. And as user2357112 also gave good thought, so I will have to check maths tomorrow for refreshing my memory.

Comment: My point is that there are other distributions that are symmetric (normal, uniform to mane two). So the choice if triangular should be justified.